# Export LD_Preload result in no such file or directory even thought the file exist

Tags: command-line, bash, matlab, caffe

I have problem with preloading compiled libraries. I tried to a path to caffe_.mexa64 in ~/.bashrc and it looks like this

```
# MATLAB
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:/home/cgal/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64
```

but after opening a new terminal I will get error that the file doesn't exist

```
(base) cgal@cgal:~$ a
/usr/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libmx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the directory the file exist in the path. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Try to add 'libmx.so' in the path too. It is normally inside the Matlab directory in 'bin/glnxa64/libmx.so'

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I already tried to input the libmx.so path into the LD_preload but the result is still the same